# Position an element always at the bottom of the page, below other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position a `<div>` always below anything else on the page. The `<div>` is inserted using javascript and it is always the last element on the page before `</body>`.

So far I have tried `clear:both` and `position:relative` which works really good but breaks if the content (above elements) are positioned absolute - Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/Hn3Nx/1/).

So what I am looking for is some css/js magic to always position a `<div>` below anything else.

I don't know how much elements are above the injected `<div>` and I don't know how they are positioned.

Unfortunately `position:fixed` is not an option.

---

**My Solution**

I ended up doing it with help of javascript:

After inserting the absolute positioned `<div>` element into the page I calculate the page height using the following function:

```
function getBodyHeight() {
  var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
  return Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
}
```

and set the top position depending on the body height:

```
element.style.top = (getBodyHeight())+"px";
```

Comment: this will always depend on the rest of your page content. We need to set certain wrapper elements, apply specific properties to it to make a sticky footer. If you ask , no matter what i do, whatever maybe the properties of other elements, my div should be always on bottom - no, can't do.

Comment: @TilwinJoy and with some JS help?

Comment: _“but breaks if the content (above elements) are positioned absolute”_ – well of course it’ll break under such circumstances, because absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the document layout flow. If you can’t refrain from using absolute positioning, then your only option is to use JavaScript to measure the dimensions of those elements and adapt the position of your bottom element accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe a relative positioned wrapper can take care of the `absolute` problem i guess.

Comment: @TilwinJoy: Only if you can give that wrapper an explicit height, because it’ll not get its height automatically from absolutely positioned descendants.

Comment: @CBroe i don't think that will be a problem, we can give `min-height: ` whatever we want the content to be..

Comment: A min-height does you no good if the actual content will take (much) less or more space … you’ll be left with either a wide gap, or have overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $('#content').height();
    $('#mydiv').css({top: height});
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hn3Nx/3/)

Keep in mind, for this to work, you need to apply `position:relative` for `#mydiv`

Comment: ok, i'll try to rewrite this in plain js because unfortunately i cannot use jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118172/setting-div-width-and-height-in-javascript

This should work together.

Comment: @Tilwin Joy You know if it is not relative, the element wont show at all because it is outside of the documentflow. The Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Hn3Nx/3/ works fine

Comment: @Pinki i ended up doing it with help of javascript

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hn3Nx/2/

CSS: set position relative for the `body`, and absolute for the `#mydiv`

```
#mydiv {    
    position: fixed;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @TilwinJoy I saw OP said "position fixed is not an option because its above the content i want it to be UNDER the content", I just can't see why.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `insertAfter()` and `inserBefore()` functions, they are what you need apart from some logic from your side.

And if you are still feeling it hard to think then detach the div using jQuery `detach()` and insert whatever you want to and then attach the div again to `<body>` using `append()`. And if you wanna do it in javascript, your task is then to figure out the equivalents of these functions. I use jQuery for these tasks.

Comment: these methods will simply inject the div at a specific position in `DOM`, it doesn't guarantee that it will not be hidden by existing content... it totally depends on the CSS... moreover there is no jquery tag in question...

Answer (score -1):

```
Please remove position: absolute; from #content this is one option.

**HTML**
<div id="content">sadas asdasd asdsa dsad sa</div>
<div id="mydiv">sadasdsa</div>


**CSS**

#content {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 0;    
    overflow: visible;
}

#mydiv {    
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```