# Change CSS Property through JavaScript. (Uses ID's and Classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I'm trying to resize a panel using JavaScript to fit a small image into a panel, and struggling badly.

It's within the bold:

```
<body id="visCinemaTransRefund"><br>
<div id="content"><br>
<ul class="PayPanel" id="paymentDetails"><br>
```

Here's the CSS that needs modifying:

```
visCinemaTransRefund .PayPanel { width: 435px; }
```

How would I be able to modify with width of this panel?

I've also got a form I'm trying to resize within CSS:

```
visCinemaTransRefund FORM (width: 1005px;)
```

Comment: You can modify the style of the element. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10118190/2165528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('paymentDetails').style.width = '1000px';
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. For the form I used:
`document.getElementById('form').style.width = '1005px';`

Comment: @MichaelMorgan Is the form ID or HTML tag?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
document.getElementById("paymentDetails").getElementsByClassName("PayPanel")[0].style.width="1000px"
```

Remember: `getElementsByClassName` return an array of elements, so using `[0]` you are indexing first element (and, of course, the only one).

Since `getElementsById` return a single elements, `getElementsByClassName` could be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to change the width of tags by accessing HTML element from the DOM using [getElement functions](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html) and setting width to it using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) javaScript function.

```
document.getElementById("paymentDetails").setAttribute("style","width:500px;");
document.getElementById("visCinemaTransRefund").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].setAttribute("style","width:1000px;");
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained the piece of code as well.

Comment: @CodingMash Explanation added :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using CSS class :

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="medium"></div>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    background-color: gray;
}

.medium {
       height: 50px;
       width: 50px;
}

.big {
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myDiv"); // or document.getElementsByClassName("className")

    if (element.className == "medium") {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").className = "big";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").className = "medium";
    }
};
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QTf7q/)

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('paymentDetails').style.width = '1000px';
```

Using JQuery:

> $("paymentDetails").width(1000);
>
> $("paymentDetails").css("width","1000px");