# Changing Height and Width of Div via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fill the div container with square boxes. Why doesn't this line work? I can't seem to change the height and width of my div `#gridSquare`.

```
$('#gridSquare').css({"height": "38.4", "width": "38.4"});
```

I'm linking the fiddle with the rest of my code.

Thank you for reading!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ojjbwms/)

What I ultimately want to do is use the squareSide variable to set the hight and width.

Comment: you should specify a unit for height and width. And when you change the size of the element, it doesn't exist yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting DIV width and height in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118172/setting-div-width-and-height-in-javascript)

Comment: Like http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5ojjbwms/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a class instead of an id (**ids should be unique**) and then you want to set the css of the square **after** you have appended to squares:

```js
var squareSide = 960 / 25;

console.log(squareSide);

for (var rows = 0; rows < 25; rows++) {
  $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
  for (var cols = 0; cols < 25; cols++) {
    $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
  }
}

$('.container').on('mouseenter', '.gridSquare', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});

$('.gridSquare').css({
  "height": "38.4",
  "width": "38.4"
});
```

```css
.container{
 background-color: grey;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 width: 960px;
 height: 960px;
}

.gridSquare{
 background-color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Also your for loop can be changed to

```
// 625 = 25 * 25
for (var i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
    $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
}
```

Comment: Do I have to wait till after to add CSS because the elemnts have to created before they can be modified by CSS? Thank you, btw.

Comment: Yeah, the elements do not exist so when you do a selector on them, the selector will return 0 elements.  I have created a new fiddle for you so you can just set the number of squares you want in a row and it will do everything else automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/5ojjbwms/8/

Comment: Ohh, cool! Thanks for teaching me new tricks. I'm seeing how you made the code more efficient and  more readable in general. Quick question though: is it always better to have one loop than have a nested loop? Even in the case when both loops will have the same limitations? Can you explain this to me a bit?

Comment: if the inner loop is just going to the same thing then I would just have one loop - easier to maintain in future as you would only have to change one section of code rather than 2

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
$('#gridSquare').css({"height": "38.4px", "width": "38.4px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of an `id`.

Add this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var squareSide = 960/25;



    console.log(squareSide);

    for(var rows = 0; rows < 25; rows++){
    $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
        for(var cols = 0; cols < 25; cols++){
            $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container');
            $('.gridSquare').css({"height": "38.4", "width": "38.4"});
        }
    }

    $('.container').on('mouseenter', '.gridSquare', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });

});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5ojjbwms/6/