# Setting height relative to `window.innerHeight` not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

This might be a very stupid question for some people, but I surely am not able to understand the problem behind this. The code is fairly simple, and goes as follows:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>####</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="resizeDiv();">    
        <div id="testElement">ABCD</div>
        <div id="secElement">ABC</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html , body{
    height:100%;
}
#testElement{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
#secElement{
    font-size:50px;
}
```

JS:

```
(function immediate(){
    document.getElementById('secElement').textContent = window.innerHeight;
}());
function resizeDiv(){
    document.getElementById('testElement').style.height = (window.innerHeight - 50) * 0.9;
}
```

Now, by this code, the `div` with `id` 'testElement' should have an height which is 90% of the `window.innerHeight - 20`. But, nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: You have to wrap the JS in a handler like window.onload(function{}) for the ready or loaded events. When your JS is executed right now, the element doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @BBrown, I tried to include the function in window.onload, but still no response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "px":

```
document.getElementById('testElement').style.height =  (window.innerHeight - 50) * 0.9 + "px";
```

Answer (score 1):

`body` tag has a `onload` handler assigned to `resizeDiv()` but your script is at the bottom of the page so, the `onload` handler can't refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById('testElement').setAttribute("style","height:" + (window.innerHeight - 50) * 0.9) + ' px';` You can find more explanation why to use it here: [Setting DIV width and height in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118172/setting-div-width-and-height-in-javascript)

Comment: Did you replace `height` with `(window.innerHeight - 50) * 0.9`?

Comment: i did everything you mentioned, and by the above answer, I guess the problem was that 'px' string. Anyways, thnx for the help

Comment: I forgot to add the `' px'` part