# CreateJs Canvas resize Bitmap

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs

I'm currently working with createJS canvas. I have an image with a predefined size into a Json file and boxes that are link to an eventListener on "mouseout" and "mouseover").

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("testCanvas");
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
stage.enableMouseOver(10);
```

Bitmap for the image:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
  var img = new createjs.Bitmap(event.target);
  stage.addChild(img);
```

then i draw my boxes (rectangles):

```
angular.forEach(..., function(value){
  var rectGreen = new createjs.Shape();
  rectGreen.graphics.beginFill("green")
    .drawRect(
       value.shapeDimension....,
       value.shapeDimension....,
       value.shapeDimension....,
       value.shapeDimension....
     );
     rectGreen.alpha = 0.01;
     stage.addChild(rectGreen);
```

my mouse events:

```
rectGreen.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
  var target = event.target;
  target.alpha = 0.35;
  stage.update();
});

rectGreen.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
  var target = event.target;
  target.alpha = 0.01;
  stage.update();
});
```

So, it's working but I have some difficulties with the canvas/image size.

1. If I don't set any width/heigth to the canvas Html, it results in a
   300*150 canvas but the image is not resized so it displays only a
   slight piece of the real image.
2. If i set width and height in the canvas html, (real size is 1700*1133), the image appears only 842*561 and the canvas takes place).
3. I tried different solution with [Setting DIV width and height in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118172/setting-div-width-and-height-in-javascript)

but nothing enabled me to set my image correctly, and responsive so that the size of my rectangles adpt to the screen size of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to dynamically resize the Canvas to the exact size of the image, you can do this:

```
//to get a variable reference to the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
//supposing the Bitmap is the variable named 'img'
canvas.width = img.image.width;
canvas.height = img.image.height;
```

If you have more elements on the screen and the total size is bigger than the image itself, you can add everything on the screen in a container, and then scale the container itself to fit the canvas perfectly, like this:

```
var container = new createjs.Container();
container.addChild(img, [your other rectangle elements here]);
stage.addChild(container);
//will downscale or upscale the container to fit the canvas
container.scaleX = container.scaleY = canvas.width / img.image.width;
```

Comment: Here is an approach to fit the contents inside the canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/4yy08pax/

Comment: Yes, if we need to make the elements fit the window size perfectly and also center them, that will work best.

Comment: Thank you for your help, about canvas size, it seems good, but I didn't look in detail to the container. This might be helpful so I'll take a look and accept it as an answer asap.